# TypeError: handlebars is not a function

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, nodemon

i have made the handlebars template config on my index.js file, but when i try to run my code with nodemon he returns me this error. anyone can help?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jXH2.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Enhla.png)

Answer (score 28):

###### Problem

Your initialization of engine on `line 8` is wrong.

###### Solution

Please change it to `app.engine('handlebars', engine());`. Check the snippet below.

###### Implementation

```js
const express = require('express');
const { engine } = require ('express-handlebars');

const app = express();

app.engine('handlebars', engine());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.set("views", "./views");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

###### Reference

- [Express-Handlebars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars)

Comment: Thank so mutch you're awesome!

Comment: Cheers from some months later, presumably following the same tutorial as OP. =)

Answer (score 10):

Insert `.engine` after handlebars, look:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({ defaultLayout: 'main' }));
```

Answer (score 1):

const { engine } = require("express-handlebars");

app.engine(
"hbs",
engine({
extname: "hbs",
defaultLayout: false,
layoutsDir: "views/layouts/",
})
);

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write the necessary details in your answer. Code-only answers are not helpful for readers. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).