# error: TypeError: handlebars is not a function

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I configured everything inside `index.js`, but when I run the server it returns this error:

```
TypeError: handlebars is not a function
```

Here is my `index.js`:

```
const express = require("express"); // comando responsavel por importar o express
const app = express(); //constante respondavel por iniciar o express
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars'); // este é o template engine
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
// configuração do Sequelize para acesso ao banco
//Configurando handlebars
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');
app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

...and my `package.json` file:

```
{
    "author": "",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "express-handlebars": "^6.0.2",
        "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
        "sequelize": "^6.12.0-beta.2"
    },
    "description": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "main": "index.js",
    "name": "admin",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "version": "1.0.0"
}
```

Could someone please help me solve it?

Comment: Hey Tauan! Could you share your `index.js` file with us? If possible, your `package.json` too.

Comment: of course, follow the code:

const express = require("express"); // comando responsavel por importar o express
const app  = express(); // constante respondavel por iniciar o express
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars'); // este é o template engine
const Sequelize = require('sequelize'); // configuração do Sequelize para acesso ao banco


//Configurando handlebars

app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}));
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');


app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine);
app.set('view', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

Comment: BTW please post it by editing the question and  copying and pasting it there, not by sharing a screenshot.

Comment: the package.json codes: {
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^6.0.2",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.0-beta.2"
  }
}

Comment: See this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33979051/typeerror-handlebars-registerhelper-is-not-a-function/33979206#33979206

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: handlebars is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962757/typeerror-handlebars-is-not-a-function)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Yes ... use handlebars like so:

```
app.engine('handlebars', handlebars.engine({defaultLayout: main'}))
```

This is how I implemented it in my app:

```
// Initialize express
const app = express();

app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "views"));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

// view engine setup

app.set("view engine", "hbs");
app.engine(
    "hbs",
    handlebars.engine({
    layoutsDir: __dirname + "/views/layouts",
    extname: "hbs",
    defaultLayout: "layout",
  })
);
```